# Высокое энергопотребление приложения iOS. Как найти виновника?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, alamofire, энергосбережение

Есть на Swift минимальное приложение (тестовое приложение, для локализации проблемы в основном):

```
import UIKit
import Alamofire


class ViewController: UIViewController {

let request = AskServer()

@IBAction func pressTheButton(_ sender: Any) {

    AskServer.sendRequest()
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
}

class AskServer: NSObject {
class func sendRequest() {

    let param: Parameters = ["X1": "12345","X2":"1","X3": "1","X4": "1", "X5": "0.0", "X6": "0", "X7": "g"]
    let myHost = "http://XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX"
    Alamofire.request(myHost, method: .post, parameters: param, encoding: JSONEncoding.default).responseJSON{response in }
}
}
```

по нажатию на кнопку идёт запрос сервера с использованием библиотеки Alamofire. Вызов отрабатывает корректно,буквально за доли секунды. Но вот затем примерно 10-20 секунд приложение жрёт процессор до 70%. Соответственно батарея на iPhone 6Plus тает на глазах.

Если закомментировать Alamofire.request - всё отлично, загрузка процессора дай бог 1% при нажатии на кнопку.

Что может так потреблять ресурсы? Помогите локализовать проблему!!!

Comment: XCode Insturment пользовал, не показывает, кто жрёт батарею. Возможно пользовал не совсем верно, т.к. делал это впервые.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте проверенную библиотеку для сетевых запросов AFNetworking. Еще могу посоветовать понаблюдать за ростом памяти после запроса. Если останавливается на каком-то значении - возможно, где-то в библиотеке проблема, если растет непрерывно и падает после didReceiveMemoryWarning - также возможна проблема где-то у вас - утечка памяти.

Comment: если я правильно понял - AFNetworking - это тот же Alamofire, только на Objective-C. Т.е. не подходит как минимум по тому параметру, что я пишу на Swift. проблему у меня с утечкой - ну так посмотрите на код, который я привёл, где тут может быть утечка? другого кода нет!

Comment: 1. objective-c компилируется вместе со swift без проблем, если что
2. у вас простой запрос. Попробуйте написать его с помощью NSURLSession
3. Так вы не ответили, память растет все время или останавливается где-то?

Comment: 1. ну чтобы скрестить Swift и Objective-C, надо как минимум выучить Objective-C, я его не заню. В любом случае спасибо!
3. при загрузке приложения потребление потребление памяти 4.3 мегабайта, при выполнении запроса рост до 5.3 мегабайта и потом не падает. При повторных запросах держится на 5.3 до бесконечности

Comment: NSURLSession, перепишите свой запрос на нативном компоненте. Это быстро. Если память нормализуется - проблема в Alamofire. Удачи

Comment: на URLSession - таже картина! Вызов отрабатывает мгновенно. Затем секунд 10 Energy Impact зашкаливает!

Comment: а можете скинуть проект? хочу посмотреть